# Fail to set the isLeaf flag in Trie

Tags: java, trie

In this simple application, I am building a trie with two words - "abb" and "abbbb".  The isLeaf failes to be set for "abb" since "should print isLeaf" is not printed after "abb".

What is missing here?

```
class Trie{
    boolean isLeaf=false;
    Trie[] children=new Trie[26];
    
    Trie(){       
    }
}

class Test 
{ 
        static void printTrie(Trie trie, int p){
            if(trie==null)
                return;
            
            System.out.println((char)(p+'a'));
            if(trie.isLeaf)
                System.out.println("should print isLeaf");            
            
            for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
                if(trie.children[i]!=null)
                    printTrie(trie.children[i], i);
            }
        }

        // Driver program
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            String[] words=new String[] {"abb","abbbb"};
            Trie trie=new Trie();
            for(var w:words){  
                Trie curr=trie;
                for(var c:w.toCharArray()){
                    curr.children[c-'a']=new Trie();
                    curr=curr.children[c-'a'];
                    System.out.println(c);
                }
                System.out.println("isLeaf");
                curr.isLeaf=true;
            }           
            printTrie(trie, -1);
        }
}
```

Comment: Missing line: if(curr.children[c-'a']==null) after line: for(var c:w.toCharArray()){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of assigning new Trie to curr.children in the first line of for loop you should check if it's there first, and reuse existing child.